# Java applet all-perminssions

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

I´m working on an java applet that must be able to perform operations that are not allowed inside the "sandbox". My java applet needs all permissions. Right now I´m running the applet on a local server.

I´ve tried to use a self-certificate for creating a signed applet but it won´t work for me.
Are there any other way to do this or do you guys know any good tutorial for creating a self-certificate?

Kind regards / H

Comment: If it needs that many privileges, why is it an applet to start with? This is like asking a word processor to run as root.

Comment: I´ve never done this before and maybe it doesn´t need to be an applet but that´s the method that I´ve chosen. What other possibilities are there for a website to communicate with client hardware? @fge

Comment: jnlp, maybe? But even then accessing local hardware is probably restricted to admin users, so you'll be SOL if the user runs it as a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

That you are asking for (all permissions for unsigned applet) would be a security exploit.

If the applet shows something rather trivial, I would suggest to rewrite in JavaScript instead. HTML 5 provides now some increased capabilities like restricted [local file system access](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

If this is a serious program, may be much better to offer it as a standalone .jar application. That way you go around the browser actions that seem getting increasingly unstable and problematic, as long as Java applets are concerned.

Comment: Would it be possible to run an applet in full permission if we implement a certificate from verisign?

Comment: Yes but this is a paid service.

Comment: It´s doesn´t matter if it´s a paid service. :)

Comment: Yes if you use an official certificate for signing and set all the permissions and stuff right it will work